# VSCode incorrectly inferring return type of Sequelize findOne and findAll as any

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, sequelize.js

I have a model defined as:

```js
import { Sequelize, Model, BuildOptions, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
interface User extends Model {
  readonly id: string;
  email: string;
  name: string;
  password_hash: string;
  readonly created_at: Date;
  readonly updated_at: Date;
}
type UserStatic = typeof Model & {
  new (values?: Partial<User>, options?: BuildOptions): User;
};
export function build(seq: Sequelize) {
  const User = seq.define(
    'User',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
      },
      password_hash: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },
    {
      timestamps: true,
      createdAt: 'created_at',
      updatedAt: 'updated_at',
    }
  ) as UserStatic;
  return User;
}
```

As is [defined in the docs](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/typescript.html#usage-of--code-sequelize-define--code-).

But, when I use this model, I get the resulting type of findAll and findOne as:

```
(method) Model<T = any, T2 = any>.findAll<User>(this: (new () => User) & typeof Model, options?: FindOptions | undefined): any
(method) Model<T = any, T2 = any>.findOne<User>(this: (new () => User) & typeof Model, options?: FindOptions | undefined): any (+1 overload)
```

But going to definition, I see:

```
public static findAll<M extends Model>(this: { new (): M } & typeof Model, options?: FindOptions): Promise<M[]>;
public static findOne<M extends Model>(
  this: { new (): M } & typeof Model,
  options?: FindOptions
): Promise<M | null>;
public static findOne<M extends Model>(this: { new (): M } & typeof Model, options: NonNullFindOptions): Promise<M>;
```

So, as can be seen, the type of M is inferred correctly, but the return type is turning from `Promise<M | null>` or `Promise<M[]>` to `any`

Anyone knows how can I fix this and get the correct type directly?

Information:

- VSCode: 1.42.0
- Typescript: 3.7.5
- Sequelize: 5.21.4

I've managed a workaround by explicit casting the return type

```js
const user = (await UserModel.findAll({
  where: {
    email: args.input.email,
  },
})) as User | null;
```

But that is extra work I don't want to have each time I use a sequelize model

Answer (score 1):

Found it, I forgot to add `@types/bluebird` and `@types/validator`